# Trying to place a UIView over top of a UIImageView to highlight a section of UIImage

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am building an app that displays text from a book on the screen.  The text of the page is a`UIImage`, and is contained inside of a`UIImageView` on the screen.  What I would like to do is highlight each line of the page, using a`UIIView` that is placed over top each line.  Here is something similar to what I am trying to achieve, except in this `UIImage`, I have multiple lines highlighted, whereas in my case, I plan to ONLY highlight one line at a time:

[image]

Each line will be covered by a`UIView` that will be of the same dimensions as the line, but I want this`UIView` to be transparent, and be a colour like Yellow, Red, or Blue, but NOT clear.  What opacity, and alpha values do I use to achieve the effect similar to the `UIImage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set backgroundColor of the UIView to the desired color.
Set alpha of the UIView to 0.5

However, the effect would be somehow different from the picture you posted as the UIView is on top and the text color will be affected.